# Finding ODE constants

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to find the constant from the following ODE describing the flow in a cylindrical pipe of radius $R$.

$0=-\frac{\Delta P}{L}+\mu\left(\frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dr}\left(r\frac{d v_z}{dr} \right )\right)+\rho g \cos(\theta)$

Where

$\frac{d v_z}{dr}\bigg\rvert_{r=0}=0$

And

$v_z\bigg\rvert_{r=R}=0$

Using the DSolve I can get the general solution.

```
eqn1 = {0 == -(dP/L) + \[Mu]*((1/r)*D[r*D[v[r], r], r]) + \[Rho]*g*Cos[B]}; 
sol1 = FullSimplify[DSolve[eqn1, v[r], r]]
```

We obtain the general profile with constant $C_1$ and $C_2$

```
{{v[r] -> C[2] + (r^2*(dP - g*L*\[Rho]*Cos[B]))/(4*L*\[Mu]) + C[1]*Log[r]}}
```

I can also find the specific profile by including the boundary conditions

```
eqn1 = {0 == -(dP/L) + \[Mu]*((1/r)*D[r*D[v[r], r], r]) + \[Rho]*g*Cos[\[Beta]], v[R] == 0, (D[v[r], r] /. r -> 0) == 0}; 
sol1 = FullSimplify[DSolve[eqn1, v[r], r]]
```

To obtain the resolved velocity profile

```
{{v[r] -> ((r - R) (r + R) (dP - 
      g L \[Rho] Cos[\[Beta]]))/(4 L \[Mu])}}
```

How can I obtain the values for constant $C_1$ and $C_2$ using Mathematica.

Comment: You have already done so when imposing the boundary conditions. It's not clear what you are asking

Comment: btw, your latex notation does not agree with your code. I used your code. In the code you have `v[R] == 0` but in Latex you wrote $v_z\bigg\rvert_{r=R}=0$ which looks like `v'[R]==0` and not `v[R]==0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
eqn1 = 0 == -(z/L) + μ*((1/r)*D[r*D[v[r], r], r]) + ρ*g*Cos[B]
ic = {v[R] == 0, v'[0] == 0}
sol1 = DSolveValue[eqn1, v[r], r]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Take derivative

```
D[sol1, r]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For bounded solution at $r=0$, `C[1]` has to be zero (since one of your initial conditions is `v'[0] == 0`. Hence the solution now becomes

```
sol2 = sol1 /. C[1] -> 0
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To find `C[2]` apply the second initial conditions

```
eq = (sol2 /. r -> R) == 0
c2 = Solve[eq, C[2]][[1, 1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

These are your `C[1]` and `C[2]`.

---

To verify, we can plugin in these in the general solution, and compare with the solution given by Mathematica

```
eqn1 = 0 == -(z/L) + μ*((1/r)*D[r*D[v[r], r], r]) + ρ*g*Cos[B]
ic = {v[R] == 0, v'[0] == 0}
mmaSolution = DSolveValue[{eqn1, ic}, v[r], r]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
sol1 = sol1 /. {C[1] -> 0, c2}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
mmaSolution == sol1 // Simplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Than you so much Nasser. This is exactly what I needed.